Issues with controller_manager Spawner for joint_state_broadcaster and diffbot_base_controller in ros2_control_demos example_2
Description
I'm encountering errors while launching the ros2_control_demo_example_2 package using ROS 2 Humble. The following issues are occurring:

Error Messages:

[ERROR] [spawner-3]: process has died [pid 44861, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args']
[ERROR] [spawner-4]: process has died [pid 44893, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner diffbot_base_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args']


Steps to Reproduce:

Installed Required Packages:

ros-humble-ros2-control
ros-humble-ros2-controllers


Cloned the repository:
git clone https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos.git -b humble


Built the workspace:
colcon build --symlink-install


Launched the example:
ros2 launch ros2_control_demo_example_2 diffbot.launch.py




Details:

The package and configuration files are from the ros2_control_demos repository, specifically the example_2 directory.
Logs:

[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/pavel/.ros/log/2024-07-25-14-32-54-093643-pavel-VirtualBox-47794
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-1]: process started with pid [47796]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [47798]
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process started with pid [47800]
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1721910774.396537587] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1721910774.398339240] [controller_manager]: update rate is 10 Hz
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1721910774.399392056] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[robot_state_publisher-2] [WARN] [1721910774.408939539] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1721910774.409079456] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1721910774.409180939] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_frontal_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1721910774.409198713] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_rear_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1721910774.409204754] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1721910774.409210094] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1721910776.684519847] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1721910778.700771960] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1721910780.717359629] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1721910782.737338214] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [ERROR] [1721910784.757250983] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-3]: process has died [pid 47800, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process started with pid [47832]
[INFO] [rviz2-5]: process started with pid [47834]
[rviz2-5] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1721910785.271573527] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1721910785.271811069] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5)
[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1721910785.356982426] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1721910787.275009139] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1721910789.295041274] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1721910791.316959309] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1721910793.340788670] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [ERROR] [1721910795.357290951] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-4]: process has died [pid 47832, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner diffbot_base_controller --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args'].


Environment:

ROS 2 Humble
Ubuntu 22.04



Additional Information

I have verified that the required packages are installed and the repository was cloned correctly. The errors persist despite these checks.
I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox.
My display in rviz2 

What I Need Help With
Please resolve the errors or at least successfully run the tutorial example ros2_control_demos example_2.

I managed to resolve the issue. Here are the steps I followed:

Completely removed and reinstalled rosdep:
sudo rm -rf /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3-rosdep
sudo apt-get install python3-rosdep


Reinitialized rosdep and updated:
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update


Updated and installed dependencies:
rosdep update --rosdistro=humble
sudo apt-get update
sudo rosdep install --from-paths ./ -i -y --rosdistro=humble


Imported repositories:
cd ~/ros2_ws
vcs import src < src/ros2_control_demos/ros2_control_demos.humble.repos
rosdep update --rosdistro humble
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y --rosdistro humble


Built the workspace:
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.sh
colcon build --symlink-install



I didn’t understand what exactly the problem was.
